# Is it necessary to serialize objects for using @RequestBody @ResponseBody annotations

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, serialization

Is a class passed as parameter in controller method and marked by `@RequestBody` annotation required to implement the `Serializable` interface?

I have same question for return value class marked by `@ResponseBody` annotation.

I also will be very grateful for explanation why the `Serializable` interface is or isn't required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not. When you return an instance from controller method annotated with `@ResponseBody` you might say that it is serialized to JSON for instance. But this kind of serialization is not the Java serialization which involves `Serializable` interface.

`@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` annotations are handled by `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` which uses `HttpMessageConverter` implementations to perform the conversion for example from object to JSON or from JSON to object.

When you look at the `HttpMessageConverter` interface there is a `canRead` method which has the following signature: `boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType);` and as you can see it is not bound to only serializable classes using generics.

**Sources and more information**

- [RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html)
- [HttpMessageConverter JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html)